# Pandas: KeyError when attempting to print value from df.loc in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I'm attempting to parse an Excel-file using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

xl_file = pd.ExcelFile("file.xlsx")

df = xl_file.parse("Sheet1")
```

Now, if I get a value (`name`) from the sheet:

```
if len(df.loc[df["Col A"].str.contains("John"), "Col B"]) > 0:
    name = df.loc[df["Col A"].str.contains("John"), "Col B"]
```

And then `print name`, the result is:

> ```
> 1    John Doe
> Name: Col B, dtype: object
> ```

or `print name.values`:

> ```
> [u'John Doe']
> ```

But if I try to retrieve the actual string with `print name[0]`, I get `KeyError`:

> ```
>   File "pandas/core/series.py", line 583, in __getitem__
>     result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>   File "pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1980, in get_value
>     tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
>   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3332)
>   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3035)
>   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
>   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6610)
>   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6554)
> KeyError: 0
> ```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is a series, and `0` is not in the series' index (check `name.index`). This explains the error message.

If you want to select the first element in the series, do:

```
name.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing my Excel file is using it's own index? (Downloaded from online source). The index for the value I was looking for is `[1]` and not `[0]`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the relation between Excel row numbers and pandas indices. But since `name` is the result of filtering (first name John), you have no way of knowing in advance which index values will or will not be in the index.